# Amount of process

Tags: c, linux

Do I understand correctly that 2 processes are created in the code below? Since one fork () call creates one thread. There are two such calls in the code, therefore, the process is created 2?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int x,y;
    pid_t pidl, pid2;

    x = 2;
    y = 3;

    printf ("Single process, x=$d\n",x);
    pidl = fork();
    if(pidl == 0) {
      printf ("New, x=%d\n",x);
      exit (0);
    }
    if(pid1 < 0){
       printf("Cannot create");
       exit (1);
    }


    pid2=fork();
    if(pid2 == 0) {
       printf ("New, y=%d\n",y);
       exit (0);
    }
    if(pid2 < 0){
      printf("Cannot create");
      exit (1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you mean _child_ process, you understand correctly. The _main/parent_ process forks at first one child which _will_ exit after displaying `"New, ..."` with code status 0, then a second child which _will_ exit after displaying `"New, ..."` with code status 0. Then the _main_ exits with code status 0 (not waiting for the childs..). Indeed, it is that if everything goes well (`printf` can crash / hang for example).

Comment: As `fork()` sets `errno`, i suggest you to use `perror()` to handle error messages.

Comment: @Zilog80 Thank you. I'm a little confused, but the correct answer should be 3 or 4. But I can't explain it

Comment: If you count the parent process plus two childs, it makes **three** process globally.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This code create **two** child process.

However you **do not make the relation** between parent and child processes by using `wait` function.
Therefore result of code change variously.

1. Child process 1 can print result before / after parent process terminated.
2. Child process 2 can print result before / after parent process terminated.

Maybe this variable result confuse you.

Comment: Thanks. So I will have 3 process: Child 1, Child 2, Parent?